# How do I synchronize local Picasa with an online folder?

Tags: software, picasa, file-transfer

I have a lot of pictures stored online using Picasa (some times ago). Is there any way to create the identical local copy of those folders (i.e., the same tags, albums, picture size, etc.)?

In other words, I'm trying to sync from the online folders back to the local folders, rather than from local to online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [download single images or individual albums](http://support.google.com/picasa/answer/39513?hl=en). You need to have the [picasa software](http://picasa.google.com/intl/en_us/) installed on your computer to do that.

You open an album. Just above the top row of images are some buttons, the last one on the right says "Download". If you click on that, one option should say "Download to Picasa". Choosing that will download the images to your computer.

The title of the link is obviously quite misleading since it downloads to the Picasa application, and thus to your computer, and is not titles "Download to your computer".

Comment: I suppose if part of the folder is already on disk, the "download to Picasa" would not be able to sync just the missing part? Rather, it can only download the entire online folder, correct?

Comment: I am not sure with the current version of the picasa software. Please note that, if you are into programming, there is an API for picasa, and people wrote sync software for it (all command-line), that focus on uploading images. I am sure you can write a two-way sync with it.